# Command-line recursive code cleanup, '){' to ') {', using grep/sed

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I'm trying to clean up my code and make it consistent, by globally adding a space between ) and {. For instance:

```
function (args){ -> function (args) {
while(1){ -> while(1) {
foreach($a in $b){ -> foreach($a in $b) {
```

I'm trying to, by command line, put something together that will go through folders and apply this rule to all files recursively, by searching for "){" and replacing with ") {", using some combination of sed and find/grep.

What's the right way to do this? I'm not sure what needs escaping due to either sed, find/grep, or the shell.

If it matters, the shell is Bash, and the code is php that occasionally generates javascript. I did a quick grep to see what might come up, and it *looks* fine to do this general search/replace, though if anyone sees potential trouble I'd love the pointer. :)

Thank you! :)

Edited to add: Solutions using common linux programs other than grep/sed/find definitely very welcome, that's just what I'm starting with. Thank you! :)

Comment: Have you considered using a code beautifier? A quick google search seems to show there's some available for PHP - might clean up other inconsistencies in your code too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/){/) {/g' file
```

To make it recursive use find:

```
find -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's/){/) {/g' '{}' +
```

Comment: Why not one `-e` with a `/g` suffix?  And why not `+` in place of `\;`?

Comment: Executed a bit on blind faith and it worked. Really looking forward to the day I actually understand that line. Thank you!! :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks incorporated all your suggestions.

Comment: For newbies like me: if you take out the ".bak" (change -i.bak to -i), it doesn't make the backup files.

Comment: Yes `-i.bak` is for safety measure only in case anything goes wrong we can recover original file. But yes it can be skipped altogether.

Comment: @heykatieben: Note that BSD (Mac OS X) `sed` requires a suffix with the `-i` option; GNU `sed` makes the suffix optional.  Be wary of using `-i` on files with multiple hard links, and of using it on symlinks.

Comment: I had in mind `sed -i.bak 's/){/) {/g' file` since I don't see any circumstances under which having several `){` pairs on a single line of code (which seems like a bad idea in the first place) would not get processed on the first sweep of the line.  For example: `echo 'if (x){if(y){if(z){do it}}}' | sed -e 's/){/) {/g'` produces
`if (x) {if(y) {if(z) {do it}}}`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks, Probably I got lost in those bracekts's mirage and typed same `s` command twice, fixed now.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, StackOverflow newbie here - done, thank you! :)

Comment: @heykatieben: No worries, I'm sure you will soon start answering questions here to help out the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
find . -type f -print |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    beautify "$file" > /usr/tmp/tmp$$ &&
    mv /usr/tmp/tmp$$ "$file"
done
```

Just replace "beautify" with whatever tool you want to invoke to clean up your code. google "PHP code beautifier" to find one or use some sed command if you're happy with that, e.g.:

```
find . -type f -print |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    sed 's/){/) {/g' "$file" > /usr/tmp/tmp$$ &&
    mv /usr/tmp/tmp$$ "$file"
done
```

If you can't find a PHP beautifier that you can call from UNIX, a C one like "cb" or "indent" might do the job.

Note that the above won't work if your file names contain newlines. There's workarounds for that if it's an issue.